# MySQL: filter date column using LIKE or MONTH?

Tags: mysql, performance, performance-tuning

I have a `CRON` task that needs to extract customers with birthdays in a given month, from a MySQL InnoDB table. The birthday field is indexed and of type `DATE`.

Filtering for April, I can query the customers table either by:

```
SELECT * 
FROM customers 
WHERE birthday LIKE "2015/04/%";
```

or:

```
SELECT * 
FROM customers 
WHERE MONTH(birthday) = 4;
```

Which one would you recommend, and why?

Comment: i would go for the second query as it will give you the exact records for the month. SELECT * FROM customers WHERE MONTH(birthday) = 4;

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The whole point of using `DATE` as a type is so the database can efficiently query the data. It's the same reason you store a number as an `INT` and not a `VARCHAR` - so the engine can make intelligent decisions. If you use the `LIKE` operator on a date, you lose the benefits of having chosen the [correct data type](http://www.brandonsavage.net/designing-databases-picking-the-right-data-types/).

Using `MONTH(birthday)` allows MySQL to grab the month portion of the birthday column that it knows adheres to the `DATE` data format. When you use `LIKE`, it's doing character-by-character pattern matching which is significantly costlier and slower to do.

If `LIKE` was sufficient, then `MONTH()` wouldn't exist. Any built in function is always going to be the choice over `LIKE` for a `DATE` query.

Answer (score 5):

I would go for:

```
SELECT * 
FROM customers 
WHERE MONTH(birthday) = 4;
```

...since it's the common way to select by month. Using `MONTH()` will call a built in function in MySQL, but if you use `LIKE` it will take it as character then do the comparison, so instead of making one operation MySQL will execute two.

Answer (score 4):

(More of a bunch of comments, plus a redundant answer.)

- Your two examples are not identical -- one is limited to 2015; the other is not.
- `WHERE birthday BETWEEN '2015-04-01' AND '2015-04-01' + INTERVAL 1 MONTH` would be able to use `INDEX(birthday)`, but that only covers those who will be born next month.
- Even if you had a `mnth TINYINT UNSIGNED COMMENT 'derived from MONTH(birthday)`, `INDEX(mnth)` is might not be used.  This is because a 'large' percentage of the the table is desired.  The optimizer might decide that a table scan is as fast.
- So, I agree with the others:  `WHERE MONTH(birthday) = 4` is probably the 'best' answer.

Answer (score 1):

I have tested for 100.000 row

`SELECT * FROM customers WHERE MONTH(birthday) = 4`; ==> 18 second

`SELECT * FROM customers WHERE birthday LIKE "2015/04/%"`; ==> 21 second

Comment: Both of those hide `birthday` in a function.  The second one may not look hidden, but it is converting it to a string.

Comment: If more than one year is involved, then the first could give more results.